# How to efficiently interlace multiple groups of lines in Vim?

Tags: vim

I am trying to interlace three groups of lines of text. For example, the following text:

```
a
a
a
b
b
b
c
c
c
```

is to be transformed into:

```
a
b
c
a
b
c
a
b
c
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Is that a real world situation or reduced test case?

Comment: Reduced test case. There are three groups that need to be interlaced but there are longer then 3 items each. I could right a macro but I was thinking there might be a better way with :g and move

Comment: Hmm, if all the `a`s are identical and the `b`s are identical and the `c`s are identical I'd simply order the first `abc` manually (`:/b/m.`, `:/c/m.`) and duplicate the resulting block 3 times (which is rather quick) but your real world needs are probably more complex.

Comment: A macro that that is close it `qa:.m +38 | j<return>38k` only issue with it is it joins the lines

Comment: Hey, this reminds me of [this one](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4575/merge-blocks-by-interleaving-lines) Don't hesitate to dive into VimScript for in this kind of situation.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a "oneliner" (almost), but you have to redo it for every unique line minus 1, in your example 2 times. Perhaps of no use, but I think it was a good exercise to learn more about patterns in VIM. It handles all kind of lines as long as the whole line is unique (e.g. `mno` and `mnp` are two unique lines).

First make sure of this (and do **not** have `/` mapped to anything, or anything else in the line):

```
:set nowrapscan
```

Then map e.g. these (**should** be recursive, **not** `nnoremap`):
`<C-R>` and `<CR>` should be typed **literally**.
`\v` in patterns means "very magic", `@!` negative look-ahead. `\2` use what's found in second parenthesis.

```
:nmap ,. "xy$/\v^<C-R>x$<CR>:/\v^(<C-R>x)@!(.*)$\n(\2)$/m-<CR>j,.
:nmap ,, gg,.
```

Then do `,,` as many times as it takes, in your example 2 times. One for all `b`s and one for all `c`s.

---

EDIT: **explanation of the mapping**. I will use the example in the question as if it has run one time with this mapping.
After one run:

```
1. a
2. b
3. a
4. b
5. a
6. b
7. c
8. c
9. c
```

The cursor is then at the last `a` (line 5), when typing `,,`, it first go back to first line, and then runs mapping for `,.`, and that mapping is doing this:

```
"xy$             # yanks current line (line 1) to reg. "x" ("a")  "
/\v^<C-R>x$<CR>  # finds next line matching reg. "x" ("a" at line 3)
:/\v^(<C-R>x)@!(.*)$\n(\2)$/m-<CR>
# finds next line that have a copy under it ("c" in line 7) and moves that line
# to current line (to line 3, if no "-" #after "m" it's pasted after current line)
# Parts in the pattern:
- ^(<C-R>x)@!(.*)$  # matches next line that don't start with what's in reg. "x"
- \n(\2)$           # ...and followed by newline and same line again ("c\nc")
- m-<CR>            # inserts found line at current line (line 3)
j                # down one line (to line 4, where second "a" now is)
,.               # does all again (recursive), this time finding "c" in line 8
...
,.               # gives error since there are no more repeated lines,
                 # and the "looping" breaks.
```

Answer (score 6):

Somewhere in the depths of my `~/.vim` files I have an `:Interleave` command (appended below). With out any arguments `:Interleave` will just interleave just as normal. With 2 arguments how ever it will specify how many are to be grouped together. e.g. `:Interleave 2 1` will take 2 rows from the top and then interleave with 1 row from the bottom.

Now to solve your problem

```
:1,/c/-1Interleave
:Interleave 2 1
```

- `1,/c/-1` range starting with the first row and ending 1 row above the first line matching a letter `c`.
- `:1,/c/-1Interleave` basically interleave the groups of `a`'s and `b`'s
- `:Interleave 2 1` the range is the entire file this time.
- `:Interleave 2 1` interleave the group of mixed `a`'s and `b`'s with the group of `c`s. With a mixing ratio of 2 to 1.

The `:Interleave` code is below.

```
command! -bar -nargs=* -range=% Interleave :<line1>,<line2>call Interleave(<f-args>)
fun! Interleave(...) range
  if a:0 == 0
    let x = 1
    let y = 1
  elseif a:0 == 1
    let x = a:1
    let y = a:1
  elseif a:0 == 2
    let x = a:1
    let y = a:2
  elseif a:0 > 2
    echohl WarningMsg
    echo "Argument Error: can have at most 2 arguments"
    echohl None
    return
  endif
  let i = a:firstline + x - 1
  let total = a:lastline - a:firstline + 1
  let j = total / (x + y) * x + a:firstline
  while j < a:lastline
    let range = y > 1 ? j . ',' . (j+y) : j
    silent exe range . 'move ' . i
    let i += y + x
    let j += y
  endwhile
endfun
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue independently tonight.  Mine's not as elegant as some of the answers, but it's easier to understand I think.  It makes many assumptions, so it's a bit of a hack:

- A) It assumes there's some unique character (or arbitrary character
  string) not present in any of the lines - I assume `@` below.
- B) It
  assumes you don't want leading or trailing white space in any of the
  a, b, or c sections.
- C) It assumes you can easily identify the
  maximum line length, and then pad all lines to be that length (e.g.
  perhaps using %! into awk or etc., using printf)

  1. Pad all lines with spaces to the same maximum length.
  2. Visual Select just the a and b sections, then `%s/$/@`
  3. Block copy and past the b section to precede the c section.
  4. Block copy and paste the a section to precede the bc section.
  5. `%s/@/\r`
  6. `%s/^ *//g`
  7. `%s/ *$//g`
  8. delete the lines left where the a and b sections were.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `xclip` you can cut the lines and use `paste` to interleave them:

1. Visual select one set of lines
2. Type `"+d` to cut them to the clipboard
3. Visual select the other set of lines
4. Type `!paste -d '\n' /dev/stdin <(xclip -o -selection clipboard)`

Answer (score 0):

Put the following as `interleave.awk` in your path, make it executable.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { C = 2; if (ARGC > 1) C = ARGV[1]; ARGV[1]="" }
{ g = (NR - 1) % C; if (!g) print $0; else O[g] = O[g] $0 "\n" }
END { for (i = 1; i < C; i++) printf O[i] }
```

Then from `vim` highlight the lines in visual mode, then call `:'<,'>!interleave.awk 3`, or replace 3 with however many groups to interleave (or leave blank for 2).

You asked for an efficient way. Interpreted languages aside, this may be the most efficient algorithm for interleaving arbitrary lines - the first group are immediately printed, saving some RAM. If RAM was at a premium (eg, massive lines or too many of them) you could instead store offsets to the start of each line, and if the lines had a consistent well defined length (at least within groups), you wouldn't even need to store offsets. However, this way the file is scanned only once (permitting use of stdin), and CPUs are fast at copying blocks of data, while file pointer operations probably each require a context switch as they would normally have to trigger a system call.

Perhaps most importantly, the code is simple and short - and efficiency of reading and implementation are usually the most important of all.

Edit: looks like others have come to the same solution - just found https://stackoverflow.com/a/16088069/118153 when reframing the question in a search engine to see if I'd missed something obvious.