# Sed, awk, Perl or other for de-interleaving text file

Tags: perl, shell, text, sed, awk

I would like a relatively compact command to perform line-by-line de-interleaving of a text file, i.e

```
a1
a2
a3
a4
b1
b2
b3
b4
c1
c2
c3
c4
d1
d2
d3
d4
```

maps to

```
a1
b1
c1
d1
a2
b2
c2
d2
a3
b3
c3
d3
a4
b4
c4
d4
```

The interleaving depth should be adjustable. The lines themselves do not contain any useful structure to assist with the process, and the example above is just a toy example for demonstration purposes. What tool can I use to do this?

Comment: Is every line in the file is in this format only i.e. `"[a-z][1-9]"` ?

Comment: You should describe your input with more detail than this.

Comment: How big are these files?

Comment: @borodin They're not particularly large files -TLP the input doesn't contain structure that can help with the process. There is only prior knowledge of the interleaving depth.

Comment: @user1207217: Then is the format of every record always just one letter and one digit?

Comment: @borodin No - arbitrary strings. The example was not meant to give an impression that structure exists that can assist with the problem that does not.

Comment: @user1207217: We cannot answer your question if you won't describe your file as we cannot know how to process each line. If there is no structure to the data then it is impossible.

Comment: @user1207217 So you are saying that the input is really just random strings, and it is their *position* that is important here? That's quite the confusion act you pulled there. I would change your sample to demonstrate this.

Comment: I also stated I wanted to de-interlace the text given an interlacing depth. I can write a C program, or a long winded script, but I wanted to know if it is possible to write a COMPACT script to achieve this, or if I had missed a tool that will do this.

Comment: @TLP: Aah! So the file is simply a flattened 2D array that requires transposing! Well done :)

Comment: @user1207217: I have updated my answer with what I think is a solution to what you are asking.

Comment: @Borodin Thank you. I was actually considering adding it as an alternative from the start, but figured it was overkill.

Comment: Thanks both .. unfortunately I can't accept both answers. It inspired my own approach though. Should I make it an answer and credit you both? It isn't very clean though ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to credit `Borodin` and `TLP` for their inputs and answers, which inspired the solution. Its ugly, but I like it

```
awk 'BEGIN{v=4}{now=(NR-1)%v; STOR[now] = STOR[now] "\n" $0;} END {for (v in STOR) print STOR[v]}'
```

It also has the flaw of printing spurious newlines (well, the ones appended to the start of the array), but I can deal with that.

EDIT:

Solution for the newlines:

```
awk 'BEGIN{v=4}{now=(NR-1)%v; STOR[now] = STOR[now] "\n" $0;} END {for (v in STOR) print substr(STOR[v],2)}'
```

Comment: Just wrote a very similar awk script and posted it at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68475906/118153.

Answer (score 2):

`sort` can do it!

```
$ sort -k1.2 your_file
```

`-k1.2` sorts by first field starting from 2nd character.

Output:

```
a1
b1
c1
d1
a2
b2
c2
d2
a3
b3
c3
d3
a4
b4
c4
d4
```

Comment: This will work if (and only if) the actual data is `a1 a2...b1 b2...`. My guess would be that those are placeholders, and the actual data might be (for example) numbers or strings, in which the order doesn't necessarily relate directly to the data itself.

Comment: I completely agree with you, @JerryCoffin. However, as the input given is like `a1 a2...` and no more info is indicated, I think my answer is enough. In case the OP indicates further requirements (and provides some of his attempts) we can guess trickier ways to do so.

Comment: As noted, the data isn't sortable. Thanks though

Comment: +1 for an easy way to do it. If fits the data so far. And it can be easily modified if the "sorting column" in the data is always at a fixed location. Please note that "sort -k..." will sort STARTING at the location. If you want to ONLY sort according to the location, use "sort -k...,...". Compare `printf 'c3c\nc2a\nb2b\na1a\n' | sort -k1.2` with `printf 'c3c\nc2a\nb2b\na1a\n' | sort -k1.2,1.2` which limits the sort on the 2nd char ONLY

Comment: Sure, @OlivierDulac! `sort -k X.Y` will not stop, while `sort -kX.Y,X.Z` will sort taking into consideration from `Y` to `Z` characters. You gave a good example.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, what you're looking at doing is reading your data into a 2D array. As you read it in, you can (for example) put the data into the array row by row.

Then when you write the data out, you traverse the array column by column. Adjusting the (de-)interleaving you do just requires a different size of array (or at least that you *use* a different amount of it, though you could leave the array size itself fixed, if you chose).

Comment: +1: nice generic way, fitting what the poster asked for without clinging too closely to the (too limited) example file he gave.

Comment: but bonus points if you provide a "generic enough" example (awk?) program ... ;) Or maybe wait first until the asker's requirements are updated.

Comment: There are no more requirements. De-interleave line-by-line given an interleaving depth.

Comment: @OlivierDulac turns out 2d array was a bit overkill, but I and others posted solutions...

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Having finally understood your question, thanks to `TLP`, I suggest this solution. It expects the depth and the input file name on the command line:

```
$ perl deinter.pl 4 interleaved.txt
```

and prints the reordered data to STDOUT.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $depth = shift;
my @data = <>;

for my $start (0 .. $depth-1) {
  for (my $i = $start; $i < @data; $i += $depth) {
    print $data[$i];
  }
}
```

**output**

```
a1
b1
c1
d1
a2
b2
c2
d2
a3
b3
c3
d3
a4
b4
c4
d4
```

---

**Previous solution**

Here is a technique that reads the whole file into memory, builds a set of keys for comparison, and sorts the indices of the data so that they can be printed in the new order.

It can be changed for your purposes by modifying the regular expression that extracts the keys fields, and changing the sort block so that the sorted order is correct.

If your file is enormous then it may be necessary to build only the array of keys in memory, and leave the rest of the data on file to be read as it is output.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'interleaved.txt' or die $!;
my @data = <$fh>;

my @keys = map [ /^(.)(.)/ ], @data;

my @sorted = sort {
  $keys[$a][1] <=> $keys[$b][1] or
  $keys[$a][0] cmp $keys[$b][0]
} 0 .. $#keys;

print $data[$_] for @sorted;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your new requirements, reordering elements based on their position in the file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @sorted;
my $depth = 4;     # the adjustable interleaving depth

while (<DATA>) {  
    my $num = ($. % $depth) - 1;  # $. is input line number
    push @{ $sorted[$num] }, $_;
}
for (@sorted) {
    print @$_;
}


__DATA__
a1
a2
a3
a4
b1
b2
b3
b4
c1
c2
c3
c4
d1
d2
d3
d4
```

Note that the script can be tested on an input file by changing `<DATA>` to `<>` and running:

```
perl script.pl input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and sort):

```
sed '1{x;s/^/1/;x};G;s/\n/\t/p;x;y/1234/2341/;x;d' file|sort -sk2|sed 's/\t.*//'
```

Comment: I wasn't clear on how this extends to other interleaving depths (particularly if interleaving depths > 10 are required, due to the use of y///). But I will spend some time deciphering it. +1 for sed