# How to interleave lines from within Vim?

Tags: vim

Given  a file  with an  even number  of lines,  how can  one
interleave the  lines from  the second  half onto  the first
half? For example, from this:

```
a
b
c
1
2
3
```

To this:

```
a
1
b
2
c
3
```

One  possible  solution would  be  writing  those halves  to
separated files and then use the `paste` utility.

```
:1,3w a | 4,6w b
:%!paste -d \\n a b
```

However, I'd  like to find  a short  way of doing  it within
Vim — using native commands.

Comment: Related posts: [Interlacing lines vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14794800/438329) and [Merge blocks by interleaving lines](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4575/778)

Comment: @PeterRincker Thank you for the references. I'm surprised I didn't find those posts before. Would you consider this a duplicated question? I'm happy to delete or merge somewhere else, although I have a feeling the search for a specific single command to do this was not really the focus on those posts.

Comment: That is the exact reason why I did not move for this question as a duplicate. I do feel that your answer would be welcomed on those questions/posts and then maybe this could be marked as a duplicate (?). Thoughts?

Comment: @PeterRincker I think the second link is actually a different question with the three groups. Mine is similar to the first, although I'm not considering any differences such as indentation (more towards something completely generic with the half-half case). To be honest, my goal here was to see if there was a shorter generic solution than mine, or if I'm overthinking / overlooking something. Initially I was going to focus the question on that ("is there a shorter way to") but then thought the format question-answer could be more helpful to future viewers.

Comment: Maybe we keep it here, since we can't mark duplicated questions cross site (or can we?). I'm always confused with stackoverflow vs. vi.stackexchange.

Comment: The solution you tried is fine and perfectly in line with the Vim and UNIX philosophies.

Comment: @PeterRincker After maturing the idea for a few days, turns out I was in fact overlooking something. I've just updated the answer with a similar but way easier operation using fixed addresses.

Comment: Instead of `:%!paste -d \\n a b`, which clears the whole buffer first, [`:r !`](https://askubuntu.com/a/180183/362789)`paste -d \\n a b` will paste it at current location.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `:g` command is frequently  used to iterate on lines and
perform  some command.  In this  case  it could  be used  to
iterate on the  lines at the second half of  the file, while
moving  lines  from  the  first half  to  their  appropriate
relative locations with `:m`.

Considering  we have  the cursor  on the  first line  at the
second half,  this line must  be preceded by the  first line
from the first half, so we can  move it there with `:1 m -1`
(move line 1  to position -1, in relation  to cursor). After
this, line 1 is now what should precede the second line from
the second  half. It is thus  a matter of moving  the cursor
down and  repeating this process, conveniently  performed by
`:g`. In short,  first jump to the first line  of the second
half with <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>%</kbd> and then:

```
:,$g/^/1m-1
```

As a  command which takes  a range of  the full block  to be
interlaced (both halves) or defaults to the entire file:

```
command! -range=% Interleave execute 'keeppatterns'
            \ (<line2>-<line1>+1)/2+<line1> ',' <line2>
            \ 'g/^/<line1> move -1'
```

```
:Interleave
```

Note:  `:Interleave`  uses  `:keeppatterns` to  prevent  the
search register  and history from  changing. `:keeppatterns`
requires Vim 7.4.083+

Comment: I've found another approach at reddit that I think worth mention: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/5zm5dn/how_to_move_a_bunch_of_lines_up_in_vim/df0p0wb

Comment: @SergioAraujo Thanks for posting that thread! It seems that the iteration + moving pattern here is a common approach to this — through `:g` or `:for`, in any direction.